# How to display date column differently when it equals a specific value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In a view I'm displaying the date column bcp and currently it default to '1900-01-01'.
How can in the view when bcp='1900-01-01' show null in the Editorfor?

Model:

```
 public partial class Training_test
    {
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public System.DateTime bcp { get; set; }

}
```

View:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.bcp, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "  datepicker" } })
```

SQL Script:

```
CREATE TABLE Training_test(
    [cart_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

    [bcp] [date] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_TrainingChecklist_bcp_1_test]  DEFAULT ('1900-01-01'),
```

Comment: Use a view model and make the transformation when you populate the view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a **ViewModel** for the Training_test class(which I assume is the model class and will map to a SQL table).
In your ViewModel class, you have to perform the logic you want while **mapping the bcp property from model to ViewModel**.

for instance:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    //you can use DateTime type like your model
    public string bcp { get; set; }
}
```

in your controller:

```
Training_test result = GetYourDataFromDB(); //retrieve your model data from db

//viewModel acts like a data transfer object and you can apply any formatting
//after the query and before sending the data back to the view
var viewModel = new ViewModel
{
     bcp = result.bcp == DateTime.Parse("1900-1-1") ? null : 
            result.bcp.ToString()
};
return View(viewModel);
```

and in your view (just make sure to assign the type of @model in your view to the type of 
the ViewModel class) :

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.bcp, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "  datepicker" } })
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something along these lines, make a calculated variable based on your bcp value?
That should look like this:

```
   //in your class
  public DateTime BcpStr => bcp.equals(new DateTime(1900,1,1) ? null : bcp; 

   //in your view
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BcpStr , new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "  datepicker" } })
```